# Identify distribution by a constant function

Tags: distribution-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On distributions over $\mathbb R$ whose derivatives vanishes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28018/on-distributions-over-mathbb-r-whose-derivatives-vanishes)

Why can I identify a distribution $G \in \mathcal{D}'((a,b))$, $\partial G = 0$ by a constant function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: fix a test function $\psi_0$ of integral $1$ and for $\phi\in \mathcal D((a,b))$, put
$$f(x):=\int_a^x\phi(t)dt-\int_a^b\phi(t)dt\int_a^x\psi_0(t)dt.$$
Check that $f$ is a test function, and compute $f'$. Then compute $G(f')$ to get the wanted result.

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik Yes, it is a typo.