# differential equation with distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm stuggeling with this differential equation:

$T'+T=0$

Where $T$ is distribution.

I found solutions in form:

$\sum_{n\in A} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Lambda_{c_n e^{-x}}$. This can be simplified to $\sum_{n\in A} \Lambda_{b_n e^{-x}}$.

Where $A \subset \mathbb{N}_0$ finite, $c_n,b_n$ arbitrary. But I don't know if I found all solutions.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: What is $\Lambda$?

Comment: For locally integrable function $f$ you define distribution $\Lambda_f(\phi) = \int f\phi$ . Where $\phi$ is test function$.

Comment: Ok. But I don't the point when you write it as a sum (you could just take one constant).

Comment: hmm that is true :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $T$ is solution, and let $S:=e^tT$, that is the distribution defined by $\langle S,x\mapsto \phi(x)\rangle:=\langle T,x\mapsto e^x\phi(x)\rangle$. We have 
$$S'(\phi)=-S(\phi')=-T(e^t\phi')=-T((e^t\phi)'-e^t\phi)=-T(e^t\phi)+T(e^t\phi)=0.$$
Conclude by [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28018/on-distributions-over-mathbb-r-whose-derivatives-vanishes).

Comment: Is there any neat way to generalize this for any differential operator $L = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n \frac{d^n}{dx^n}$. So I'm looking for solution of $L(T) = 0$?

Comment: I found this link http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Applied_linear_operators_and_spectral_methods/Differential_equations_of_distributions